# How to integrate Mediawiki with Redmine?

Tags: mediawiki, redmine

I saw a patch for this issue but I don't know how to solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you like to put Mediawiki into Redmine, cause Redmine has already a good wiki. Furthermore it wouldn't be that simple, cause Mediawiki is PHP where as Redmine is Ruby on Rails...

Comment: Actually I think mediawiki is the best. And I already have a wiki. So I want to continue to use it.

Comment: Not to resurrect an old topic, but here's another scenario that I find myself in: our company has an extensive set of documentation stored in an instance of MediaWiki; we recently launched Redmine for issue tracking and project management, and we would like those wiki pages available within certain Redmine project, without needing to manually copy all the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [comment](http://www.redmine.org/issues/4863#note-2) on the Redmine website which suggests using the [Tab plugin](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/Plugin_List#Tab-plugin) as a workaround, you could try that.